# spying on node child_process using jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, child-process, spy

I am new to nodejs and jasmine. Working on a small project for learning javascript/node and jasmine. I am trying to spy on the object child_process in node and see the method 'spawn' is called with the arguments specified.

The jasmine error reports that the spawn is never called when the object (Nndb in this case) that invokes the spawn method is called. But the actual work is performed by the child process as I see the results printed in the console.

Here is the failure I see when running the jasmine-node script:

> Failures:
>
> 1) scrape for xyz  spawns child process
>     Message:
>       Expected spy spawn to have been called with [ '../src/scrape_nndb.js', 0 ] but it was >never called.
>     Stacktrace:
>       Error: Expected spy spawn to have been called with [ '../src/scrape_nndb.js', 0 ] but >it was never called.
>      at null. (/Users/arun.bakt/skunkWorks/scraping/spec/nndb_spec.js:30:41)
>     at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
>
> Finished in 6.024 seconds
>   1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure, 0 skipped"

The jasmine test file for it:

```
require('../src/nndb.js');

describe("scrape for XYZ", function() {

    var child = require('child_process');

    it("spawns child process", function() {

        var nndb = new Nndb();
        var child_process =  nndb.child_process;
        spyOn(child_process, "spawn");

        runs(function(){
            flag= false;
            nndb.scrapeForXYZ('../src/scrape_nndb.js', 0);
            setTimeout(function() {
                flag = true;
            },6000)
        });

        waitsFor(function(){
            return flag;
        }, "Scraping done", 6000);

        runs(function(){
            expect(child_process.spawn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('../src/scrape_nndb.js',0);
        });
    });

});
```

The file nndb.js that is being tested below:

```
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;

var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

var child_process = require('child_process');

Nndb = function() {

    this.child_process = child_process;

    this.spawn = this.child_process.spawn;

};

Nndb.prototype.scrapeForXYZ = function( phantomScriptToRun, offSet) {


    var child =  this.spawn('phantomjs', [phantomScriptToRun, offSet]);

    child.stdout.on('data',function(data){

         console.log("MATCH "+decoder.write(data));

    });

    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    child.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });

    return 0;

};



exports.Nndb = Nndb;
```

Comment: Well, the spy didn't get set up properly - I'm not sure why not. If the spy was working, the function's actual code would *not* have run. Spies, by default, replace the functions they watch, rather than watching and reporting. If you want the function to run normally as well, you need to do something like `spyOn(child_process, 'spawn').andCallThrough();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see the problem. You create `nndb`, and `nndb` sets `nndb.spawn` equal to `nndb.child_process.spawn`. Then you set a spy on `nndb.child_process.spawn`, but because `nndb.spawn` has already been copied off of it, the spy isn't applied to both. When `nndb.scrapeForXYZ` calls `nndb.spawn`, the spy is unaffected.

Try this:

```
it("spawns child process", function() {

    var nndb = new Nndb();
    var child_process =  nndb.child_process;
    spyOn(nndb, "spawn");

    //...
        expect(nndb.spawn).toHaveBeenCalledWith( //...

}
```

Comment: Hi, What you have observed is correct. Slight modification in it is that I still have to spy on child_process and not nndb. Nndb is the test subject. After removing the line "this.spawn = this.child_process.spawn;" from the nndb constructor and adding "spyOn(child_process, "spawn").andCallThrough();" made the test pass. Thank you for your answer. Now I have to figure out how to test the child.stdout.on and child.stderr.on methods in the spawned child_process –  arunbakt 9 hours ago